# Firebase notifications test Production possible?

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications

I'm working on an app that uses firebase notifications.  Everything worked fine in development but for my life I can't get it working in production on iOS.  One simple thing I noticed is that in the firebase console, when you send a test notification, there is no setting for development/production.  When my server sends a notification I get "Error: Invalid Registration".  I have tried everything including deleting all of my certificates and profiles and building from stratch.  I have checked for production settings everywhere in my code and I am out of ideas.  I think firebase is just sending to the wrong apple server and there doesn't seem to be a way of testing it inside firebase.  This seems like a key component of the whole thing so maybe I am missing something obvious, like that the production/development flag is set by the registration key itself, but 1- I dont know how firebase would know that and 2- when I send a notification from my server I need to specify if sandbox is true or false.  So, I get the feeling that this setting is just missing from the firebase console, and there is no way to "test" a production notification.  Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase products don't have any settings for targeting environments such as dev/test/production within a single project.  The general advice from Firebase for isolation of environments is to create different Firebase projects for each environment.  This gives you a clear separation between test data and production data.

I strongly suggest reading the documentation on [configuring multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

Comment: I don't need a separate environment, I just need this one to go to production.  I can't find a single setting anywhere in firebase on how to do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, as I said, there is no setting.  You should consider using multiple projects anyway.